# I have a problem with list using argv, TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, arrays, list, argv, sys

I am working in a program using sys library by Python, and I faced an issue with writing the argument in a proper way,

```
## Main function to show main window.
def main():
    app = application_uri(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow()
    win.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

I tried these but did't work

```
def main():
    app = application_uri(int(sys.argv))
    win = MainWindow()
    win.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

{TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'}
and

```
## Main function to show main window.
def main():

index = sys.argv[1]
if isinstance(index, int):
app = application_uri(index)
else:
print("Index must be an integer")

    main()
```

Comment: What argument does `application_uri()` expect?  A list, or a single integer?

Comment: `sys.argv` is always a list of strings.  So its elements will never have type `int`.  They will always have type `str`.  Your `if` condition is equivalent to `if False`.